# Skip over levels of a directory when importing python package

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a directory structure like:

```
Folder_in_PYTHONPATH/
├── Package1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── Class1.py
│   │   ├── Class2.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── test
│       └── testfile.py
├── Package2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── Class1.py
│   │   ├── Class2.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── test
│       ├── test1.py
│       └── test2.py
.
.
.
```

When I import things from this folder, I need to always type

```
import Package1.src.Class1
```

Is there any way to set up my `__init__.py` so that I can just type

```
import Package1.Class1
```

instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add them into your packages' `__init__.py` files so they look like:

```
from src import Class1
from src import Class2
```

Have a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

I would recommend putting the *.py files in the top level folder of their package to get the `import Package_1.Class1` behaviour you are after. The unit tests can stay in their own folder to keep them separate.

Comment: This allows me to use `from Package1 import Class1` but doesn't let me `import Package1.Class1`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put the `Class*` files in the top level?

Comment: Not really other than it would be a lot of work since there are a lot of Package directories, and it seems to make organizational sense to distinguish between the classes and the unit tests

Comment: You can keep the unit tests in their own folder; presumably they're not part of the api.

Comment: Okay, I've gone with the directory restructuring solution, although I'm still kind of curious about whether there's another way. If you write it up as another answer, I'll accept it

Comment: I would like to put all my source files in src folder, since there are other config files in project root.

Comment: An important point is that there should be no dependency in between Class1 and Class2 !