# Using python __init__.py to "skip" a directory

Tags: python

I make a lot of little python packages to help with this that or the other.  As such, I have a directory, say `/packages` where I like to keep all of my handy tools, and I put that on the python path `$export PYTHONPATH=/packages`.

Now suppose that I put an `__init__.py` into `/packages/my_package`.  I can `$python -c "import my_package"` successfully.  However, if I do the typical thing with my directory structure (since I still have docs and whatnot) as `/packages/my_package/my_package/hello_world.py`, then having an `__init__.py` in `/packages/my_package/my_package` is insufficient to be able to import `some_code.py`.  I can add an `__init__.py` into my root `/package/my_package`, but then I have to `import my_package.my_package.hello_world`, which conflicts with the normal "installed" way of importing.  How do I set up my root-level `__init__.py` so that imports "skip" the intervening "code" directory, and `import my_package.some_code` works as expected?

### tl;dr

Given this directory structure:

```
packages/
    my_package/
        __init__.py
        my_package/
            __init__.py
            hello_world.py
```

with the `packages` directory in my `PYTHONPATH`.  How do I compose my `__init__.py`s so that `import my_package.hello_world` works?

Comment: Why do you have duplicate `my_package` directory? Is it possible to rename the inner one?

Comment: @ChenA Sure, but I'm not sure how the exact naming of the inner directory is important.  In django apps, for instance, it is customary to have a nested directory with the same name as the project.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460281/skip-over-levels-of-a-directory-when-importing-python-package), although the answer there is less than satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write import in every *init.py* file. You can try the below code, it might need some modifications as per your need. But overall this would be the format.

```
packages/
    my_package/
        __init__.py
        **from .my_package import main** 


        my_package/
            __init__.py
            **from .hello_world import main** 


            hello_world.py

            def main():
                #Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the deduplicated directory structure:

```
packages/
    my_package1/
        __init__.py
        my_package2/
            __init__.py
            hello_world.py
```

It is sufficient to add the following in the `__init__.py` file of `my_package1`:

```
from .my_package2 import hello_world
```

That's a relative import of the `hello_world` module in `my_package2` into the parent package `my_package1`.

Comment: It should work, but I don't see why you want to share package names. Usually creepy when working on a terminal where the full path is not shown.

Comment: Interestingly, this causes `from my_package1 import hello_world` to work, but `import my_package1.hello_world` fails.

Comment: This also has the unfortunate side effect that importing *other* modules from `my_package1` executes code from `hello_world.py`.  So, for instance, if `hello_world.py` prints "hello world", then `import my_package1.sub_package27.whatever` will print "hello world"

Comment: Should you be printing directly in your module? Why not add a `if __name__=='__main__':...` to barricade those. I'm guessing the prints are for debug only.

Comment: Probably not.  But it still seems a shame to be forced to import `my_package.subpackage34` when all I need is `my_package.subpackage27`.

Answer (score 0):

This solves my particular use-case, in a non-python way.  Instead of putting `/packages` on the `PYTHONPATH`, I just wrote a script that puts all of its subdirectories on to the `PYTHONPATH`.  This allows me to use all of the modules in the "normal" way, without having to install them, and without having the weird root `__init__.py`.  It does not answer my question, however, and I feel like there must be a nice pythonic way to handle it.

Specifically, I put this at the end of my `~/.bashrc`

```
LOCAL_PYTHON_PACKAGES="[my_package_directory]"
for d in $LOCAL_PYTHON_PACKAGES/*/ ; do
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$d
done
```

Of course, this only works for packages for which the actual source code is one directory down.  It would be better to handle this in a package-specific format.