# Error when importing a whole subfolder with submodules with __init__ file

Tags: python, python-import, relative-import

I have the following structure:

```
folderA
├── __init__.py
└── folderB
    ├── __init__.py
    └── folderC
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module.py
```

I want to be able to import `folderC` without having to call `folderB`, like the following way:

```
from folderA.folderC.module import *
```

And I have written the following things in the files:

`folderA/__init__.py`:

```
from .folderB import *
```

`folderA/folderB/__init__.py`:

```
# empty
```

`folderA/folderB/folderC/__init__.py`:

```
from .module import hello
```

`folderA/folderB/folderC/module.py`:

```
def hello():
  print("hello world")
```

But I received the following error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folderA.folderC'

How can I import `folderC` without having to name `folderB` in the process?

Comment: There is a great explanation of relative imports in python here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Not quite, I have read that post but I don't find any reason there why the scheme I have created doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip over levels of a directory when importing python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460281/skip-over-levels-of-a-directory-when-importing-python-package)